# Why is my paragraph exceeding the hr line which is below the paragraph on resizing?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

The problem is that I have an image on the left side of my screen and I have a paragraph on the right side of my screen and I have an hr line below the paragraph and the image. So whenever I resize the browser window, the paragraph just goes below the hr line because it gets compressed(squashed) on resizing. I don't want the paragraph to go below the hr line even if I resize the browser window. I want the paragraph to go below the image but not exceeding the hr line. If you want to see what is the problem please check out my website and resize the browser window to see the problem.

Link to website: http://www.greenfield-school.com/AboutUs.html

Thanks

This is the HTML:

```
<h3><b>About Us</b></h3>
    <hr style="border: 2px solid green; width: 88%">
    <div class="row2">
  <div class="column2" style="background-color:;">
    <img class="pic img-responsive" src="Icon.jpeg" style="height: 200px; height: 230px">
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:;">
    <h5 class="welcome"><b>Mission</b></h5>
     <p class="paragraph" style="font-family: book antiqua"><li class="vision1">To care for, respect and encourage all children equally, regardless of gender or ability.</li>
     <li class="vision1">To encourage our pupils to develop a sense of self worth, self discipline, personal responsibility and consideration for others.</li>
     <li class="vision1">To provide an enjoyable, challenging and purposeful atmosphere for our pupils.</li>
     <li class="vision1">To value and encourage the special talents and strengths of pupils.</li></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.vision1 {

    list-style-type: square;
    font-family: book-antiqua;
}

.row2{
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem 6rem;
}


.column {
  flex: 60%;
  height: 200px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.column2{
  flex: 0%;
  height: 0px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

h3{
    padding: 5rem 5rem 0rem;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: But as you can see that I also want a line below the ABOUT US h3 tag so I should also place a line below the ABOUT US part and I have the other line outside the row but I just forgot to show it in the code

Comment: You can check the website to get better understanding and try to resize the browser window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me offer you an alternative - I can't seem to trigger that auto-adjust on the `container` `height`. But this works seamlessly:

This is your HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column one"> Column 1 - this is where your picture is</div>
  <div class="column two"> Column 2 - this is where your paragraph is</div>
</div>
<hr />
```

This is CSS:

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.column{
  float: left;
}

.column.one{
    //style for column one here
}
.column.two{
    //style for column two here
}

hr{
  clear: both;
}
```

This will adjust the height of the `container` based on on the biggest height of either `column one` or `column two`

I have checked this code here [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzpogQ)

Comment: .row2{
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem 6rem;
  overflow: flex;
  clear: both;

}

Comment: I did this but this doesn't solve the problem either

Comment: OK, So at least it does not go below the hr line but the scroll bar pops up isn't there any way that the hr line just goes below as the text takes up the space instead of the scroll bar?

Comment: Try using the above approach. It has been working for me for years now. I have added a codepen link so that you can test it. Flexbox is great but it can be a pain figuring these kinds of tings out sometimes. But the above approach should work seamlessly

Comment: OK, so now I tried it but the problem is that the paragraph is coming below the picture. I tried float right to the column where my paragraph is but that doesn't move my paragraph next to the picture right now it is coming below the picture.

Comment: Ok, Now I got it !

Comment: Well, please edit this answer and add what you have fixed and mark as answer and leave it for other people who might experience the same issue?

Comment: By the way, Well Done for figuring it out. I am not sure what was wrong with my code about, did it work? or what did you add?

Comment: I just used your code but I was copying your code wrongly but then I  re checked and it worked.

Comment: well Done @Soban, I am Glad you made a good use of it. Please mark it as an answer if you're satisfied.